# Deleting file from internal storage in Android

Tags: android, delete-file, android-internal-storage

I was saving file to internal storage now I want to delete it. The problem is, I don't remember the name of that file so I can't use this `myContext.deleteFile(fileName);` approach. How to get the name of that file and delete it?

Comment: you cant delete without file name i guess

Comment: Use a file explorer and look what filename looks familiar. Or you look at the creation date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use file methods from Context, Android saves that file into app's directory (and encrypt it, compared to File.()) method). So, you can just clear app data and that file will be removed